# Exception while saving in a list

Tags: android, list

I have created a class  called Placeslist when i try to make a list of Placeslist and save objects in it i got **Android.java.lang.NullPointerException**
This is placeslist class

```
public class Placeslist {

     @Key
     public String status;

     @Key
        public String id;
        @Key
        public String name;
        @Key
        public String reference;

        @Key
        public double lat;

        @Key
        public double lon;

     public Placeslist(String status,String id,String name,String reference,double lat,double lon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.status=status;
            this.id=id;
            this.name=name;
            this.reference=reference;
            this.lat=lat;
            this.lon=lon;

    }
```

and this is the code when i try save an object in the list

```
Placeslist placeslist=null;

            String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
            List<Placeslist>places=null;
            JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = result.getString("name");
                String id = result.getString("id");
                String reference = result.getString("reference");
                JSONObject latitudes = result.getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location");
                double lon = latitudes.getDouble("lng");
                double lat = latitudes.getDouble("lat");
                placeslist=new Placeslist("OK", id, name, reference, lat, lon);
                places.add(placeslist);

            }
```

Comment: Use debug and post what line you got NullPointerException.

Comment: Also one comment about your design: maybe you need to rename class `Placeslist` to `Place`.

Comment: @Souvlaki thanks i will update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing:

```
places = new ArrayList<PlacesList>();
```

or

```
places = new LinkedList<PlacesList>();
```

`List` is an `interface` and cannot be used directly to create an object. A child class should be used instead.

Comment: i got this error Cannot instantiate the type List<Placeslist>

Answer (score 0):

Because your list is null. Fix:

```
List<Placeslist>places = new ArrayList<Placeslist>();
```

Also you could rename PlacesList to Place, because PlaceList is just one element in the list.

Comment: i got this error Cannot instantiate the type List<Placeslist>

Comment: Sorry, I forget List is just interface. Updated version works.